# CSS border trouble

Tags: html, css

I have a slight problem with CSS borders. I have 9 camera feeds streaming directly to one webpage. I want a neat white 1px border between the nine of them, but no matter how hard I try, no dice. Currently my code is:

It SHOULD give me a neat 1px border everywhere, right?
Nope. What it gives me is this:

[view cams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHrNg.jpg)

```css
body{
 background-color:#FFF;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}    
.cam{
 width: 33%; 
 height: auto; 
 float:left;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:white;
 border-width:0px;
}

#topleft{
 border-bottom-width:1px;
 border-right-width: 1px;
}

#topright{
 border-bottom-width:1px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
}

#bottomleft{
 border-top-width:1px;
 border-right-width: 1px;
}

#bottomright{
 border-top-width:1px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
}

#middle{
 border-top-width:1px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-width:1px; /*Note that I didn't even include the top border to try and fix the problem.*/
}
```

```html
<img class="cam" src="*IP ADRESS*" id="topleft">
<img class="cam" src="*IP ADRESS*">
<img class="cam" src="*IP ADRESS*" id="topright">
<img class="cam" src="*IP ADRESS*">
<img class="cam" src="*IP ADRESS*" id="middle">
<img class="cam" src="*IP ADRESS*">
<img class="cam" src="*IP ADRESS*" id="bottomleft">
<img class="cam" src="*IP ADRESS*">
<img class="cam" src="*IP ADRESS*" id ="bottomright">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need to add 4 or 5 `id`, just use this -

```
.cam + .cam {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

to get a vertical `border` between each.

now for a horizontal `border`, this one should do -

```
.cam {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

However, this one adds a horizontal `border-bottom` at the last low also. To remove that also, you can do this -

```
.cam:nth-child(7), .cam:nth-child(8), .cam:nth-child(9) {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7dcoq2q/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cam {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<img class="cam" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" id="topleft">
<img class="cam" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg">
<img class="cam" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" id="topright">
<img class="cam" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg">
<img class="cam" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" id="middle">
<img class="cam" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg">
<img class="cam" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" id="bottomleft">
<img class="cam" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg">
<img class="cam" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" id="bottomright">
```

Currently your widths are 33% which when you apply a border will add extra width and height to the image.

By applying `border-box` your image will use width + padding + border to create the 33% width of each item.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I want exactly 1px between every box. Not 2px. Not my demands so I can't make compromises sadly.

Comment: Ive updated my answer to show the snippet working... The problem you have now is your own borders that your creating. Click on the "Run code snippet above"

Answer (score 2):

If using a table, `border-collapse` will solve this.

If without using a table, then please run the code snippet below,

```css
.cells {
  width: calc((100% - 2px)/3);
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="cells cell-1"></div>
  <div class="cells cell-2"></div>
  <div class="cells cell-3"></div>
  <div class="cells cell-4"></div>
  <div class="cells cell-5"></div>
  <div class="cells cell-6"></div>
  <div class="cells cell-7"></div>
</div>
```